# Getting List of Running processes and applications

Tags: command-line, process, startup-applications

How can I see which application and what processes are running recently after the login using terminal command.

Comment: just as one big list or would you like to separate applications from other processes?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Not one big list I would like to separate applications from other process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script lists all processes, and splits them in *applications* and *other processes*.

As definition for an application, I practice that the process is initiated from a `.desktop` file (since practically all applications are represented by a `.desktop` file), and that the `.desktop` file appears in Dash (the `.desktop` file has no line: `NoDisplay=true`).

**Work to be done:**

The script, as it is, derives the application's process name from the (last section of-) the command, found in the desktop file, and also from information, found in the possible symlinks it might refer to (e.g. in case of `LibreOffice` > process name: `soffice.bin`). In some cases however, an application runs from a remote script, called from the `.desktop` file. In those cases, the process will not be recognized as an application.

The script gives an output like:

```
Processes, related to applications:
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1933 ?        00:03:55 firefox
18091 ?        00:00:00 dia
18162 ?        00:00:01 soffice.bin
31167 ?        00:00:06 alarm-clock-app
31174 ?        00:00:09 nautilus
31301 ?        00:00:20 dropbox
31998 ?        00:01:35 idle3

Other processes:
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:01 init
    2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
    3 ?        00:00:02 ksoftirqd/0
    5 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0H
    7 ?        00:00:15 rcu_sched
    8 ?        00:00:08 rcuos/0
```

etc...

**The script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess

def createlist_appcommands():
    dtfile_dir = "/usr/share/applications"
    dtfile_list = [item for item in os.listdir(dtfile_dir) if item.endswith(".desktop")]
    commands = []
    for item in dtfile_list:
        try:
            with open(dtfile_dir+"/"+item) as data:
                searchlines = data.readlines()
                command = [line for line in searchlines if line.startswith("Exec=")
                           and not "NoDisplay=true\n" in searchlines
                            ][0].replace("Exec=", "").replace("\n", "").split("/")[-1].split(" ")[0]
            commands.append(command)
        except Exception:
            pass
    return commands + [trace_symlinks(item) for item in commands if not trace_symlinks(item)== None]

def trace_symlinks(command):
    target = subprocess.Popen(["which", command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    location = (target.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")).split("\n")[0]                                                          
    check_filetype = subprocess.Popen(["file", location], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    filetype = (check_filetype.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")).split("\n")[0]
    if "symbolic link" in filetype:
        return filetype.split("/")[-1].replace("' ", "")
    else:
        pass

def createlist_runningprocs():
    processesb = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "-e"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process_listb = (processesb.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")).split("\n")
    linked_commands = [(item, item[24:]) for item in process_listb][1:]
    applist = createlist_appcommands()
    print("Processes, related to applications:\n  PID TTY"+" "*10+"TIME CMD")
    matches = []
    for item in applist:
        for i in range(0, len(linked_commands)):
            if item[:15] in linked_commands[i][1] and len(item[:15])/len(linked_commands[i][1]) > 0.5:
                matches.append(i)
    matches = sorted(matches)
    for i in range(0, len(linked_commands)):
        if i in matches:
            print(linked_commands[i][0])
    print("\nOther processes:\n  PID TTY"+" "*10+"TIME CMD")
    for i in range(0, len(linked_commands)):
        if not i in matches:
            print(linked_commands[i][0])

createlist_runningprocs()
```

**How to use**

Copy the script in an empty file, save it as `processes.py`, run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/processes.py
```

*Edit: updated my answer, rewrote the script.*

*Improvements:*

- *(much) better performance*
- *the script now traces and recognizes applications, initiated via symlinks (which may have another process name). Although exceptions are always possible, they should be rare now.*

Comment: @algosig I rewrote the script, added tracing via symlinks. exceptions should be rare now; I suggest you use this one :)

Answer (score 8):

Generally `ps` command does it.

If you type [`man ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ps.1.html), you will get the manual for this command, and there you can check which flag you will need. For example, `ps -e` will list all running processes in the system.

Another command is `top` which will show an active view of all running process.