# How can I get list of all running applications?

Tags: command-line

*System monitor* in Kubuntu can filter running processes so that I can choose **Program only** choice
so my question is how can I get the same results by commands ?

Comment: Take a look at the man pages for top or ps:  `man top` or `man ps`.  `htop` is a nifty program to have installed, as well.

Comment: It's not an unreasonable question to ask!

Comment: @Dk Bose I am trying to build an app that can collect information about the time spent by the user on those apps , so what I want is how can list them that's it

Comment: @KirollosNasr That's not easy to do.  Many programs are running in the background and the system doesn't distinguish (as far as I know) between whether a program is doing work or whether a user is actively using it.   The nature of some programs is to not have a user do anything interactively -- but it's still doing something useful behind the scenes.

Comment: @Ray Thank you for your reply , I think the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509457/getting-list-of-running-processes-and-applications) can help me , it shows that we can recognize the processes I mean , they are initiated from a **.desktop** which I could trace. Although there are some exception that I think I could handle them